Getting items from a realtime database in a random order
In some cases where we get items from a database we have this kind of code:
  const [dataRcdArray, setDataRcdArray] = useState<never[]>([]);
  .....
  snapshot.forEach((child:IteratedDataSnapshot) => {
    setDataRcdArray(arr => [...arr, child] as never[])
  });

In the code above items from a realtime DB are found and stored in an array called dataRcdArray. This works fine except if we want the final result to be randomly ordered.
In order to get some randomness and not always the same order as above.
I can use this code block:
snapshot.forEach((child:IteratedDataSnapshot) => {
  const randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
  if (randomVal%2) setDataRcdArray(arr => [...arr, child] as never[])
  else setDataRcdArray(arr => [child, ...arr] as never[])
});

This code would work perfectly if there were only two items in the DB. But starting from three and above, it is easy to see that the resulting randomness is far from perfect. One can think of what happens with three items for instance. The last item read from the DB always ends up in the final or the starting position of the final array, but never in the middle; showing that this is not true randomness.
So comes my question. Besides these two options:
setDataRcdArray(arr => [...arr, child] as never[])
setDataRcdArray(arr => [child, ...arr] as never[])

Is there a way which works in this case (knowing that dataRcdArray is a state variable) to insert the last read item at an arbitrary position in dataRcdArray and not only at the beginning or at the end (this would allow me to have true randomness) ?
Note: By true randomness, here I mean within the limits of what Math.random() can provide !

Are you asking how to randomly order an array in JavaScript?

Not really, I have several algorithm in mind for that. And if it was only for JS there are several options in the language to manipulate arrays. My question is more specific to the way to access and set an arbitrary element in my particular code. Like how could I put child in 2nd or 3rd position of arr (instead of just start or end). I have tried a few things but it seems many functions are not working in this particular use case.

I might not understand the difference. If you first put them in the array in the order they come back in from the database, and then shuffle with the code I linked - How would the result of that be any different of that be different from what you want?

Probably because dataRcdArray is a state variable, I have some difficulties to use it as a normal array. I may also not have had a close enough look to the code you suggested. In the mean time I found a way to reach what I want with some code I plan to put as an answer. This code is most likely to be equivalent to yours in a different shape.

I can finally reach the result I want by using the code below:
  setDataRcdArray(arr => [...arr, child] as never[])

  if (shopCount>=2) {
    randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * (shopCount))
    if (randomVal) {
      setDataRcdArray(arr => arr.slice(randomVal).
                              concat(arr.slice(0,randomVal)) as never[])
    }
  }

